# VBA worksheetfunction gamma_dist using in cycle for..next

Tags: vba, excel

My cycle:

```
For n = 1 To 30000 Step 1
    a = m * n
    b = delta ^ a
    c = f1 ^ (a - 1)
    d = WorksheetFunction.Exp(-f1 * delta)
    e = WorksheetFunction.Gamma_Dist(f1, a, 1, 1)
    konvolucia = (b / e) * c * d
Next n
```

over the `e` is displaying

> runtime error.'423' - Property or method not found

Can I ask you where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message

> Property or method not found

tells you, the issue is there is no `WorksheetFunction` called `Exp`.

If you are looking for the `exp` function defined as:
`Exp(n) =` `e` raised to the `n`<sup>th</sup> power, where `e = 2.71828183…`.

Then use `d = Exp(-f1 * delta)` instead.

---

**Side note**
`Gamma_Dist` awaits a `Boolean` as last argument:

```
Gamma_Dist(Arg1 as Double, Arg2 as Double, Arg3 as Double, Arg4 as Boolean)
```

So you should use `True` or `False` instead of `1` as last argument. In VBA `True` is `-1` and `False` is `0` so don't use `1` even if anything beside `0` casts to `True` when converted to Boolean.

Comment: Thank you so much,   I also have problem with this function                            {For x = 1 To 15 Step 1
        g = WorksheetFunction.Binom_Dist(f1, r, q, 0)
        hustota = g * konvolucia
    Next x}          runtime error 1004

Comment: Please don't post questions as answers/comments. Instead [edit] your original question and add which values for your variables are you using to run this loop when the error occurs? Add the full error message and in which line it occurs. Without seeing the code and knowing the values we cannot help.

Comment: Sorry, that was the wrong edit link in my comment above. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44236269/edit) **your own original question** instead and add all the requested data.